# How can I know the network Reachability by AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

***setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock*** can get status when network reachability changed, but it can not get status when App Launch.

I know **Reachability** can do this, but I don't know whether **AFNetworking** has this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[AFHTTPClient -networkReachabilityStatus]`, as shown in [the docs](http://afnetworking.github.io/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/networkReachabilityStatus).

Answer (score 0):

> networkReachabilityStatus
>
> The reachability status from the device to the current baseURL of the
>   AFHTTPClient.
>
> @property (readonly, nonatomic, assign) AFNetworkReachabilityStatus
>   networkReachabilityStatus
>
> Discussion
>
> The reachability status from the
>   device to the current baseURL of the AFHTTPClient.
>
> Warning: This property requires the SystemConfiguration framework. Add
>   it in the active target’s “Link Binary With Library” build phase, and
>   add #import  to the header
>   prefix of the project (Prefix.pch).
>
> Declared In AFHTTPClient.h

Comment: I have try to use the property like this:

`client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    
    if (client.networkReachabilityStatus == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable) {
        // Not reachable
    } else {
        // Reachable
    }`

But the value of `client.networkReachabilityStatus` is 4294967295.It will always go to //Reachable. where am I wrong?

I have #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h> to Prefix.pch and add SystemConfiguration.framework.